# Building golang project in docker - cannot find package in any of $GOPATH or $GOROOT

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, grafana

I have a project with the path `/Users/me/Documents/dev/grafana/src/github.com/grafana/grafana`. This project uses several other projects, for example:

```
/Users/me/Documents/dev/grafana/src/github.com/BurntSushi/toml
/Users/me/Documents/dev/grafana/src/github.com/Unknwon/com
```

I can build everything fine on my machine, but when I try to build within Docker, I get a bunch of `cannot find package` errors.

```
go install -v ./pkg/cmd/grafana-server
pkg/login/ldap_settings.go:7:2: cannot find package "github.com/BurntSushi/toml" in any of:
/usr/local/go/src/github.com/BurntSushi/toml (from $GOROOT)
/go/src/github.com/BurntSushi/toml (from $GOPATH)
pkg/services/notifications/codes.go:9:2: cannot find package "github.com/Unknwon/com" in any of:
/usr/local/go/src/github.com/Unknwon/com (from $GOROOT)
/go/src/github.com/Unknwon/com (from $GOPATH)
```

When I build myself, I have `$GOPATH=/Users/me/Documents/dev/grafana/` -- in my Dockerfile I have:

```
FROM golang:latest AS build

RUN go version

ENV SRC_DIR=/go/src/github.com/grafana/grafana/
ENV GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1

COPY . $SRC_DIR
WORKDIR $SRC_DIR

[... dependency installations ...]

# Building of Grafana
RUN npm run build
RUN go run build.go setup
RUN go run build.go build
```

I can't figure out why this step (Wich starts in the `RUN go run build.go setup` step) keeps reporting that it can't access the packages.

I've looked around for similar questions, but almost everything related doesn't specify building in Docker (and the ones that do aren't super helpful for this scenario).

Comment: This is what I use: https://github.com/immortal/immortal/blob/master/Dockerfile, hope can give you an idea

Comment: Thanks. It looks almost like it's expecting those paths to exist already. They don't, and they should be fetched when issuing the [build.go setup](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/master/build.go#L409) (I think)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below and see if that works.

Step 1: Install go dep (go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep)

Step 2: Run command `dep init` within your project. This will create a Gopkg.toml and Gopkg.lock

Step 3: Change your docker file

```
FROM golang:latest AS build

RUN go version

WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/grafana/grafana/
ENV GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1

COPY . .
RUN go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep && \
    dep ensure && \
    npm run build && \
    RUN go run build.go setup && \
    RUN go run build.go build && \
```

How dep works is when you run command `dep ensure` it pulls all the dependencies and puts them inside the vendor directory and can be easily accessed by your code.